# Trouble Scraping a Table with Python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape the table data from this website: https://www.playnj.com/atlantic-city/revenue/

Yet when I try to print the table, it returns None. Can someone assist me with this?

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
base_url = 'https://www.playnj.com/atlantic-city/revenue/'
resp = requests.get(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "html.parser")
october_table = soup.find('table', {'id': 'tablepress-342-no-2'})
print(october_table)
```

This returns None and I am unsure as to why - Ideally (and perhaps I am wrong here) - If my objective is to get ALL the data from ALL the tables it is more efficient to use the same class wrapper as all the tables and I would use the following 2 lines instead (but maybe not).

```
all_tables = soup.findAll('table', {'class': 'dataTables_wrapper no-footer'})
print(all_tables)
```

However this also returns None. Any help here would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: You get `403 Forbidden` in response. You should try with required headers

Comment: @Sers something like headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'}
resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers) ?

Comment: yes, at start use headers with `User-Agent`. You can also display `resp.text` to see if you didn't get warning for bots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this page check `User-Agent` header.

It works even with incomplete `"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"`

**BTW:** this table has different ID: `'id': 'tablepress-342'`

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.playnj.com/atlantic-city/revenue/'
r = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})
print(r.status_code)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

october_table = soup.find('table', {'id': 'tablepress-342'})
#print(october_table)
for row in october_table.find_all('tr'):
    for item in row.find_all('td'):
        print(item.text)
    print('---')
```

Result

```
200
---
Bally's
$3,799,907 
$180,229 
$9,107,610 
$13,087,746 
---
Borgata
$14,709,145 
$1,060,246 
$35,731,777 
 $51,501,168 
---
Caesars
$7,097,502 
$ -
$14,689,045 
$21,786,547 
---
Golden Nugget
$3,311,223 
$84,387 
$11,356,285 
$14,751,895 
---
Hard Rock
$7,849,617 
$ -
$16,619,183 
$24,468,800 
---
Harrah's
$4,507,262 
$205,921 
$19,372,672 
$24,085,855 
---
Ocean Resort
$5,116,397 
$65,276 
$13,245,998 
$18,427,671 
---
Resorts
$2,257,149 
$ -
$9,859,813 
$12,116,962 
---
Tropicana
$4,377,139 
$152,876 
$17,501,139 
$22,031,154 
---
Total
$53,025,341 
$1,748,935 
$147,483,522 
$202,257,798 
---
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}

df = pd.read_html(requests.get(
    "https://www.playnj.com/atlantic-city/revenue/", headers=headers).text)[0]

df.to_csv("out.csv", index=False)
```

Output:

```
          Casino Table & Other       Poker Slot Machines Total Gaming Win
0        Bally's    $3,441,617    $183,255    $9,780,559      $13,405,431
1        Borgata   $16,744,564  $1,631,575   $40,669,801      $59,045,940
2        Caesars   $13,785,260         $ -   $14,530,482      $28,315,742
3  Golden Nugget    $5,237,258     $92,647   $11,728,116      $17,058,021
4      Hard Rock    $7,155,391         $ -   $16,338,090      $23,493,481
5       Harrah's    $5,555,330    $222,323   $19,794,846      $25,572,499
6   Ocean Resort    $4,965,900     $82,686   $14,459,903      $19,508,489
7        Resorts    $3,328,916         $ -   $10,566,342      $13,895,258
8      Tropicana    $4,531,234    $159,957   $18,957,670      $23,648,861
9          Total   $64,745,470  $2,372,443  $156,825,809     $223,943,722
```

CSV File: [view-online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/ea748e6158dba66efa3979f332fe3fd8/out.csv)

Answer (score 1):

Request with headers:

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.4,tr;q=0.2',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
}

resp = requests.get('https://www.playnj.com/atlantic-city/revenue/', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "html.parser")
tables = soup.select('table.tablepress')
```